# C# How to Change DataTable Column Dimensions in A DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, datagridviewcolumn

I am  trying to set the width and height of the cells in a Column in a DataTable/DataGridView.

I understand from  the internet it is done like this:

```
grid.Columns[0].Width = 10;
```

however this gives me an outOfRange Exception. If I try to find it by name then i get a  null reference.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Date");
        dt.Columns.Add("Smørrebrød");
        dt.Columns.Add("Minismørrebrød");
        dt.Columns.Add("Buffet");
        dt.Columns.Add("Daily Orders");

        DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
        grid.DataSource = dt;
        grid.Width = 1000;
        grid.Columns[0].Width = 10;
        window.Controls.Add(grid);
```

Can someone illustrate how this is properly done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the width set operations as shown below

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Date");
dt.Columns.Add("Smørrebrød");
dt.Columns.Add("Minismørrebrød");
dt.Columns.Add("Buffet");
dt.Columns.Add("Daily Orders");

DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
grid.DataSource = dt;
grid.Width = 1000;
Controls.Add(grid);
grid.Columns[0].Width = 10;
```